# Make web page width responsive to every screen device

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have a page on my web app that is overlapping on small screen devices. How can I make it responsive using media queries?

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Admin Console</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons>
        <ion-button (click)="home()">Home</ion-button>
        <ion-button routerLink="./users">Users</ion-button>
        <ion-button routerLink="./orders" routerLinkActive>Orders</ion-button>
        <ion-button routerLink="./suppliers">Suppliers</ion-button>
        <ion-button routerLink="./updates">Database Updates</ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Please share more details. What exactly is not working? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried using the max-width : 100%; for the <ion-content> div. its still overlapping so i'm considering using the media queries

Comment: @premo How it looks like now and how do you want it looks on small screens?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **ion-grid** - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/grid
The grid is a powerful mobile-first flexbox system for building custom layouts.

It is composed of three units — a grid, row(s) and column(s). Columns will expand to fill the row, and will resize to fit additional columns. It is based on a 12 column layout with different breakpoints based on the screen size. The number of columns can be customized using CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you just open up Chrome/Edge, click on the "Toggle for device emulation" button on the top-left corner of the Dev Tools window, then drag the sides of the page in the "Responsive" device emulation option, drag the sides closer to see how it looks, note the width and the height, and write a media query in which you change the appearance of the page at a specific width and height. The syntax for a media query is:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Where the `max-width: 1000px;` is the maximum width required to trigger the media query to do what you have written inside the braces. You could change `1000px` to the width you saw when you inspected the page.

I know I have to give you the code, but seeing as you have not said what code you've tried so far, I do not know.